# preg_match: fixing an issue with blocking https:// URL link in a comment BOX

Tags: php, preg-match

So short story short:
I check many stack over flow article with similar situation and only found this one
1) [Detecting a url using preg_match? without http:// in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762260/detecting-a-url-using-preg-match-without-http-in-the-string?rq=1)
2) [preg_match to only allow https:// in an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561834/preg-match-to-only-allow-https-in-an-url?rq=1)

but didn't answer my problem

[image]

So I'm doing an preg_match in my php file to stop people putting URL from Bot and Troll. But when I test it with this code it doesn't work :(. So if they SUBMIT the message with any URL prefix, it won't be sent. But it not working

```
if(preg_match('/(https|ftp|http):/i',$comments))
        {
        // prevent form from saving code goes here
        echo "<script>alert('Please Correct your message');</script>";
        // echo "<script>window.open('contactus.php','_self');</script>";
        }
```

but for some reason , it bypass the preg_match and is still sent even with the script pop up. Is there something im doing wrong cause my co-worker use this code on a different site and it work. Thanks

[image]

PS: HERE the whole code if you need more context thanks

```
<?php
session_start();
    /*if ($_SESSION['company'] != "RapidPay") {
        //redirect to the logout pag
        $redirect = 'index.php';
        include  './includes/redirect.php';
     } 
    if(!$_SESSION['userid']) {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }*/
/*  if(!$_SESSION['userid']){
        header("location:login.php");
}*/
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $useremail = $_SESSION['uemail'];
    $uphone = $_SESSION['uphone'];
    $usecurity = $_SESSION['usecurity'];

    include './includes/dblogin.php';
$currentPage = 'contactus';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    $dontsend=0;
    $mailstatus="";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        //catch spambots
        $honeypot = FALSE;

        if (!empty($_REQUEST['honeypot']) && (bool) $_REQUEST['honeypot'] == TRUE){

            $honeypot = TRUE;
            $dontsend=1;
            # treat as spambot

        }


        $username=$_POST["uname"];

        $phoneno=$_POST["phno"];

        $email=$_POST["email"];

        $comments= $_POST["message"];

        if(preg_match('/(https|ftp|http):/i',$comments))
            {
            // prevent form from saving code goes here
            echo "<script>alert('Please Correct your message');</script>";
            // echo "<script>window.open('contactus.php','_self');</script>";

            }


        if (preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $comments) || strpos($comments, 'erect') !== false){

            $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            $subject = 'russian spammer ip /erectile spammer ip - RPSBS';
            $message = $comments . " " . $ipaddress;
            $from = $eemail;
            $headers = "From:".$from;
            $to= 'EMAIL';
            # mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            $dontsend=1; 
}



   if ($dontsend!=1){

            $ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

            $message="";

            $message.="<table>";

            $message.="<tr height='40'><td colspan='2' style='vertical-align:top'>Details of the Person</td></tr>"; 

            $message.="<tr height='40' ><td style='vertical-align:top; width:120px'><b>Name:</b></td><td style='vertical-align:top'>".$username."</td></tr>";

            $message.="<tr height='40' ><td style='vertical-align:top'><b>Mobile Number:</b></td><td style='vertical-align:top'>".$phoneno."</td></tr>";        

            $message.="<tr height='40' ><td style='vertical-align:top'><b>Email ID:</b></td><td style='vertical-align:top'>".$email."</td></tr>";           

            $message.="<tr height='40' ><td style='vertical-align:top'><b>Message:</b></td><td style='vertical-align:top; text-align:justify'>".$_POST["message"]. "<br>this message is from ip address " . $ipaddress ."</td></tr>";

            $message.="</table>";



            $to="EMAIL";


            $sub="RapidPay - Contact US Form Submission From ".$username;

            $headers="";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            $headers .="From: ".$email."\r\n";

            mail($to, $sub, $message, $headers);

            $mailstatus="Your mail has been sent";

            //phpinfo();



       }






    }

?>
```

Comment: I did not read all of your code now. But try adding the s-flag to your preg_match-pattern. The s flag makes the regex look for multiple lines. And if you dont have the s-flag in your preg_match-pattern, it would only find URLs within the first line of the string.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but i can wait if you can look at the code later :). the only problem with your advice is that in the second picture, the Http is on the first line, So i dont think the s-flag would work if the issue is also on the first line

Comment: @Bernhard are you coming to look at the code anytime soon :)?

Also if you can, can you help me solve this issue too, the person answer was ok but still didn't understand it

thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120541/using-an-if-statement-in-php-but-not-working/54121100#54121100

Comment: You set a bracket wrong! Check the if-statements :)

Comment: @Bernhard i double check it, i don't understand, what did  i do wrong?

Comment: Your block for sending the email is within if (preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё]/u', $comments) || strpos($comments, 'erect') !== false){

Comment: @Bernhard oh thanks , didnt see that error. my focus is the first IF statement with if(preg_match('/(https|ftp|http) but thanks for correcting that error :)

Comment: @Bernhard like this 
if (preg_match('/[А-Яа-яЁё])/u', $comments)

Comment: @Bernhard wait NVM, i still dont see the error, i added a parentheses but that wasnt the issue, what bracket am im missing?

Comment: lol move the last } above if ($dontsend!=1){

Comment: @Bernhard oh sorry, the real code has that :). must of not copy correctly